# SQL Server Native Client 11 should it be on the server or on each client machine

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-native-client

I need to connect a number of MS Access client applications to a SQL Server database. Does the Native Client need to be installed on each client machine or just on the server?

Answer (score 1):

On each client machine.
Here is a link with some additional info.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937733.aspx

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought, but wanted confirmation since I couldn't find an explicit explanation.

Comment: You can of course use the standard SQL driver, and that is included on most machines. The advantages of native 11 over the standard legacy one is the newer data types (especially date/time) are supported. So the tradeoff of using the native 11 driver is you have to "install" it on each machine. For this reason, I tend to work with the legacy driver.